# Copy a string to the beginning of a file in Java

Tags: java, file

I want to write a string into the beginning of a file, How do I do that?

I don't know how to add a string at all.. This is what I did so far:

```
  public static void prepend (String filename, String data) throws IOException{

    FileOutputStream file= new FileOutputStream(filename);

}
```

(i) The `write()` method accepts only bytes- What should I do in order to use it in my case?

(ii)-How do I copy the string to the beginning of the file?

And- If someone knows about a web-site that has all the Writers\Readers and all these streams arranged and well explained- I will really appreciate it, I'm losing my mind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To write *text*, you need to create a `Writer` - such as `OutputStreamWriter`. You *can* use `FileWriter` instead, but I prefer to wrap a `FileOutputStream` in an `OutputStreamWriter` as that way I can control the encoding.

You can't really prepend to the start of a file though - you'll have to write the new text to the start of a new file, then copy the contents of the old file afterwards, then rename the files if necessary. Exactly how you do that will depend on the contents of the existing file.

Comment: It's conceivable (especially for small files) that you could read in the contents of the file to memory, overwrite the original with your "prepended" text, and then dump what you read in originally. This has draw backs, of course, high memory consumption for large files and not as safe it it screws up appear offhand. But on systems where file-io is prohibitively expensive, it's an alternative.

Comment: @glowcoder: Well, it requires just as much reading and writing to be done - but it doesn't need as much disk space in the meantime of course.

Comment: When you write FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f); Does it makes f writeable? or does it make new file? cause in my case, I alreay have this file, so I wonder what happens. thanks

Comment: @Nir: It will overwrite an existing file, truncating it.

Comment: Ah I see. For some strange reason I was thinking you would slurp the new file back in and spit it out... it's too late in the day (US West coast) to blame that on lack of coffee, too... In retrospect, it would seem it may end up on the disc anyway if your memory swells and some is written to disc, in effect making it worse!

Answer (score 8):

You could just use RandomAccessFile class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("test.txt", "rws");
    byte[] text = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    file.readFully(text);
    file.seek(0);
    file.writeBytes("Prepend 8");
    file.write(text);
    file.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a number of things.

Create a PrintStream passing in the "file" you've created then use println(data) to print the data or just print(data) if you don't want a system dependent new line added after it.

You can create an outputstreamwriter to wrap the outputstream you've created and then wrap that with a printwriter to get the same behavior as above.

The writer approach is better all around as it handles the character encoding, if you should need that.

Comment: I would recommend *against* using `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` unless you *really* don't want to know when all your data has been lost due to swallowed IOExceptions...

Comment: Ok I agree with your point.  I don't think from the description of the problem that it would factor in for this particular person, but as I said, I fully agree with your statement regarding swallowing of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BufferedWriter, i.e.

```
// read the existing contents of the file into a string builder   
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}

// open the file for writing
BufferedWriter s = new BufferedWriter
    (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename)));

// prepend your text
s.writeLine("some line of text to prepend");

// rewrite the file contents
s.writeLine(sb.toString());
```

Comment: You forgot to specify the character encoding in the `InputStreamReader` and in the `OutputStreamWriter`.

Comment: Does the StringBuilder will copy all the file as one big line? couldn't it be a problem? Can we copy it to a new file instead?

Comment: If your file is huge I suppose it could be a problem. You could also copy line by line to a new file and rename the file at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void prepend(String filename,string data) throws IOException{

 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
 StringBuilder reply = new StringBuilder();
 reply.append(data); 
 String str = new String();

 while( (str = in.readLine())!=null)
   reply.append(str);

 str = reply.toString();
 BufferedWriter out= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
 out.write(str);


 if(in !=null){
 try{ in.close();} catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
 if(out!=null)
try{out.close();} catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is running code.

private static void addHeader(File fileName) {

```
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =null;

    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    String newFileName = fileName.getAbsolutePath() + "@";

    try {

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);
        fileOutputStream.write("yourCopiedDataHere".getBytes());

        fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            fileOutputStream.write(("\n"+sCurrentLine).getBytes());

        }
        fileOutputStream.flush();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
            if (br != null)
                br.close();

            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();

            System.out.println(fileName+" is deleted "+ fileName.delete());
            new File(newFileName).renameTo(new File(newFileName.replace("@", "")));


        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```