# How to append a new line to beginning of an existing file in java?

Tags: java

Assuming I have a txt file located in /mypath/sampletext.txt. How do I append a new line to the beginning of the file with the following in Java while preserving the original text file's contents?:

```
String startStr ="--Start of File--";
```

Looking for a way to do this without having to create an intermediary 2nd file and make modifications only to the existing file if possible.

Comment: Create new file, write the line you want to add, read and dump the rest of content of old file, then remove the old file and rename the new file to old file's name.

Comment: It is not possible to add extra data to the beginning of file without creating a new file. If you are just "changing the content", or appending to the end of file, then it is still possible I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy a string to the beginning of a file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339342/copy-a-string-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Read file contents first, prepend new line to that like `contents = newLine + contents`, then write the new conent in the same file (dont append).

Comment: This is assuming that the content of the file fits in RAM, and you know the encoding of the file.

Answer (score -1):

well,three ways ,may help you

1.

//true: is append text to fie
        FileWriter write = new FileWriter("file_path",true);
         writer.write(content);

1. //open randomFile and "rw"
       randomFile = new RandomAccessFile("file_path", "rw");
       // file length
       long fileLength = randomFile.length();
       //point to end index
       randomFile.seek(fileLength);
       //write
       randomFile.writeBytes(content);
2. BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true)));
    out.write(conent);

Comment: First and last are wrong. They will append to file, not prepend as OP wants. The second one is also append, as I see it.

Answer (score -2):

New answer is updated...

In this I've use few more FileIO classes & may be their one is deprecated API but If you are aware with Java FileIO classes you can easily fix it.

Here I append new line at the start of file rather than append it to the end of file..

If any issue please comment again....

Try this, I think it will help you..

```
try
    {
        //Append new line in existing file.
        FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("onlineSoultion.txt");
        DataInputStream dr = new DataInputStream(fr);

        String startStr = "--Start of File--\n";
        //String startStr;

        while (dr.available() > 0) {
            startStr += dr.readLine();
            //System.out.println(startStr);
        }
        dr.close();
        fr.close();

        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("onlineSoultion.txt");
        writer.write((new String()).getBytes());
        writer.close();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("onlineSoultion.txt", true)));
        out.println(startStr);
        out.close();

    }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with OP's question

Comment: that's sounds better :)  but there are rooms to improve: 1. I can't imagine there is still people using String += in such way.  It is one good example of inefficient string manipulation.  2. You don't need to read all the things in a string and write it back.  Why not have a loop and, read some data from in file and write it immediately?

Comment: Yes you are right... Here I made simple example so everyone can understand further as per requirement experts can improve as per requirements..